# Youtube API and Web audio api

Tags: javascript, audio, youtube, youtube-api, web-audio-api

I made an audio visualizer using the Web Audio API. And would like to extend that to youtube video's however i'm not sure if this is even legal. As splitting the audio from the video is considerd illegal. However I have no problem playing the video aswell. but i /need/ the audiostream to get the data for the visualizer.

Any suggestions/examples of how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if its possible to pluck the audio directly from a youtube URL without intermediate steps ... however here is how to extract an audio file once the video is downloaded [using a python script youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl)

```
youtube-dl -c https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aJzYioSDi4
```

now you will have the video file of an arbitrary video URL (youtube, vimeo or others, etc...)

```
ls -la "GoPro HD Hero camera - 2010 Post Office Bike Jam-4aJzYioSDi4.mp4"
```

now use the excellent command line [audio/video tool ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to extract audio from video (not the least of ffmpeg's magic)

```
ffmpeg -i "GoPro HD Hero camera - 2010 Post Office Bike Jam-4aJzYioSDi4.mp4"  -vn -acodec copy "GoPro HD Hero camera - 2010 Post Office Bike Jam-4aJzYioSDi4.aac"
```

at last you have an audio file from the URL

```
ls -la "GoPro HD Hero camera - 2010 Post Office Bike Jam-4aJzYioSDi4.aac"
```

[ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)  is not limited to above codec (mp4 to aac) as it picks up your choice of output file suffix

Comment: Thank you. Looks very promising.

Comment: should be able to use `youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 ....` in one go